# ASP.NET Core MVC 3.0.0 issues

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

How to add a stored procedure using ASP.NET Core 3.0.1 MVC?

I currently have this code:

```cs
public class HRMSContext : DbContext
{
    public HRMSContext(DbContextOptions options)
            : base(options)
    {
    }

    //protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    //{
    //    modelBuilder.Entity<EmpSalaryDetails>()
    //                .MapToStoredProcedures();
    //}

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        foreach (var foreignkey in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes().SelectMany(e => e.GetForeignKeys()))
        {
            foreignkey.DeleteBehavior = DeleteBehavior.Restrict;

        }

    }
    //public DbSet<M_DEPARTMENT> tbldeptarment { get; set; }
}
```

Is this the right way or not? And I have add empty migration and up method create stored procedure and update database. But I have to call that stored procedure in `DbContext`. But how to call it in `DbModelBuilder`?

And how to call a stored procedure in controller?

Answer (score 0):

> How to add stored procedure using ASP.NET Core MVC code-first approach

You can use [`MigrationBuilder.Sql`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.migrations.migrationbuilder.sql?view=efcore-3.1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Migrations_MigrationBuilder_Sql_System_String_System_Boolean_) method in the `Up` method of your migration class to create a stored procedure, like below.

```
public partial class SPCreate : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        //...

        var sp = @"CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetDepartments]
            AS
            BEGIN
                select * from Departments
            END";

        migrationBuilder.Sql(sp);
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

> How to call stored procedure in controller

To execute a stored procedure, you can call `FromSqlRaw` method, like this:

```
var departments = _dbcontext.Deptarments.FromSqlRaw("EXECUTE GetDeptarments").ToList();
```

Besides, you can refer to [this article](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/raw-sql#leveraging-ado.net-via-the-context.database-property) that shows how to make use of existing stored procedures and execute raw SQL queries.